# Multible RewriteRules result in Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

forcing this to work makes my kind of crazy so i hope you can help.

I use Rewrite Rules and .htaccess to make my dynamic URL

```
example.com/page.php?id=1
```

look like this

```
example.com/1
```

using

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    page.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

, and it works perfectly fine so far.
But i also want to hide the filetype in the URL ( `impressum.php` to `impressum`) using

```
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

So both Rules are working completely correct as long as i dont use them both at the same time. When i do so, which looks like this (my complete file)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    page.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

,i get an Internal Server Error. I tried different versions, for example change the positions and so on, but i allways get this error.

So my question is: how do i get both rules together and working, while the URL ending is still hidden and the `example.com/1` works too?

Thank you very much for any answer

Comment: That's because both rewriterule conditions `(.*)` and `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)`  will both match `/1` in your URL. How is the server going to know the difference between one non real file and another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Check if the PHP file exists and route accordingly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

# If not, pass the request to page.php if it contains A-Za-z0-9-
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$    page.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need two separate rules. Rewrite conditions will only get applied to the immediately following rule and with your php extension rule, you must check that the php file *exists* before adding the php to the end:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    page.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```